# How do I drop a column from multiple pandas dataframes using a loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple dataframes in a list CGdfs.

```
CGdfs = [CGdf_2002, CGdf_2003, CGdf_2004, CGdf_2005, CGdf_2006, CGdf_2007, CGdf_2008, CGdf_2009, CGdf_2010, CGdf_2011, CGdf_2012, CGdf_2013, CGdf_2014, CGdf_2015, CGdf_2016, CGdf_2017, CGdf_2018]
```

I want to drop a column named 'Plot' from all these dataframes using a loop.
How do I do this?

I have tried the below, this does not work

```
for df in CGdfs:
   df = df.drop('Plot', axis =1)
```

Comment: Please explain why it does not work. Do you get errors? Post the traceback

Comment: Have you tried with `del df["Plot"]`?

Comment: @cs95 just asking->  how is `df.pop('col_name')` for loops ?

Comment: @anky_91 It does god's work - it removes a column but also returns it. Problem is you can only pop one at a time so it is limiting if you want to drop multiple columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
for df in CGdfs:
    df.drop(columns = ['Plot'], inplace= True)
```

Comment: Both of them are wrong. Can you figure out why?

Comment: The first one does not appear to re-assign the new df(modified) to the df in the list.
Second one seems to work(tested it out)

Comment: Yes! Removed the incorrect answer from your post.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that it's not applying the drop to the original DataFrame object. Try:

```
for df in CGdfs:
    df.drop('Plot', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

When you inspect the elements of CGdfs the "Plot" column should be removed.